Script Implementation of SN74HC165NSR

I have a PCB connected to my Raspberry Pi via its PiSound Header. It has 7 SN74HC165NSR shift registers. I'm trying to write a basic script that can read the ON / OFF state of the switches on the PCB boards. Unfortunately no switch input is being registered. Based on the below information, does anyone know what the issue could be? I'm using Raspberry Pi's BCM number system for more context.
Schematic: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_g_Kf1r067VoHnoNN8dOSQZ1N2xbncJT/view?usp=sharing
Components:
Marquardt 6425.0101 and
Marquardt 6450.0005
PiSound Pinout: https://blokas.io/pisound/docs/specs/
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

SCLK_PIN = 23
SH_LD_PIN = 1
DATA_PIN = 27

NUM_REGISTERS = 7
NUM_INPUTS = NUM_REGISTERS * 8

def setup_gpio():
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
    GPIO.setup(SCLK_PIN, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setup(SH_LD_PIN, GPIO.OUT)
    GPIO.setup(DATA_PIN, GPIO.IN)

    GPIO.output(SCLK_PIN, False)
    GPIO.output(SH_LD_PIN, True)

def read_shift_registers():
    GPIO.output(SH_LD_PIN, False)
    time.sleep(0.005)  # More delay for stability
    GPIO.output(SH_LD_PIN, True)
    time.sleep(0.005)  # More delay for stability

    register_values = []
    for _ in range(NUM_INPUTS):
        GPIO.output(SCLK_PIN, True)
        time.sleep(0.005)  # More delay for stability
        value = GPIO.input(DATA_PIN)
        register_values.append(value)
        GPIO.output(SCLK_PIN, False)
        time.sleep(0.005)

    print("Bits read:", ''.join(map(str, register_values)))

    return [int(''.join(str(x) for x in register_values[i*8:(i+1)*8][::-1]), 2)
            for i in range(NUM_REGISTERS)]

def cleanup_gpio():
    GPIO.cleanup()

def main():
    setup_gpio()
    try:
        while True:
            data = read_shift_registers()
            print(f"Raw data from shift registers: {data}")
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Exiting program")
    finally:
        cleanup_gpio()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

I have this LED control script that works for controlling LEDs on the same PCB so I know that my cables are connected correctly:
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

# Define GPIO pins
PIN_SCLK = 23  # Serial Clock pin
PIN_LAT = 27   # Latch pin
PIN_BLANK = 5  # Blanking pin (active low)
PIN_SIN = 22   # Serial Data Input pin

# Number of TLC59282DBQR drivers
NUM_DRIVERS = 5

# Number of outputs per driver
NUM_OUTPUTS = 16

# Setup GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(PIN_SCLK, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(PIN_LAT, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(PIN_BLANK, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(PIN_SIN, GPIO.OUT)

# Initialize pins
GPIO.output(PIN_SCLK, GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(PIN_LAT, GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(PIN_BLANK, GPIO.LOW)  # Active low, low to enable outputs

def send_bit(value):
    GPIO.output(PIN_SIN, value)
    GPIO.output(PIN_SCLK, GPIO.HIGH)
    time.sleep(0.0001)
    GPIO.output(PIN_SCLK, GPIO.LOW)
    time.sleep(0.0001)

def latch_data():
    GPIO.output(PIN_LAT, GPIO.HIGH)
    time.sleep(0.0005)
    GPIO.output(PIN_LAT, GPIO.LOW)

def enable_output():
    GPIO.output(PIN_BLANK, GPIO.HIGH)  # Set high to disable outputs

def disable_output():
    GPIO.output(PIN_BLANK, GPIO.LOW)  # Set low to enable outputs

def all_leds_on():
    for driver in range(NUM_DRIVERS):
        for output in range(NUM_OUTPUTS):
            send_bit(GPIO.HIGH)
    latch_data()

try:
    disable_output()  # Enable outputs only once at the start
    while True:
        all_leds_on()
        time.sleep(0.0)  # Refresh every second to maintain state

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Script interrupted by user.")

finally:
    enable_output()  # Disable outputs before cleanup
    GPIO.cleanup()  # Cleanup GPIO settings


Didn't you ask the same question already?

@Justme Hi. I hadn't provided enough information in the first post and made a bit of progress since the last one–this time I know the pins and provided a bit more info. My apologies for the double-post. I deleted the old one.

you should have edited the first one, instead of posting this one

The old deleted post explained that there is code to read buttons via HC165 but the GPIO pin number mapping in code to actual HC165 through some board was unknown.

@jsotola Thank you. Edited to include the fact that none of the switch input is registering.

@JelaniThompson How did you come up with those pin numbers? It might explain what went wrong. Where did you look up which pin number is which?

Hey @Justme I came up with that number based on the schematic included in the post. It uses the same logic as the pin number variables in the LED script that I posted. It's the BCM system. Pin 9 would be BCM 27 and so on. The PiSound docs have a good example: https://blokas.io/pisound/docs/specs/
This logic worked perfectly for the LED control script, but isn't working for the switch control script for some reason.
The BCM system is for the PiSound pins. SH/LD is Pin 1 on the button / switch driver.

In your LED example, you call pin 27 a latch pin. In your shift register read program you call pin 27 a data pin. For reading that shift register chain you need to read QH (derived from pin QH on shift register U4). Is that what you are doing ? Also the clock pin is different from the LED example

@6v6gt thank you for your response. Yes, I looked up the BCM equivalent to Pin 9 and it shows up as 27.

@JelaniThompson I don't understand the pin mappings, they do not seem to match or make any sense. Have you double checked them?

To read the shift register chain you need to read QH (serial data out) which is pin 3 on the PISOUND header which is GPIO pin 7 on the Pi (not GPIO pin27 as you have it). You must also write to CLK which is pin 10 on the PISOUND header which is GPIO pin 4. At least that is how I understand it from the schematic and the pin out document you have supplied. These pins are of course different from those necessary to read the LED registers. That you are using in part the same pins in both scripts is a clear indication that you have got it wrong since the hardware is different in both cases.

Hey @6v6gt thanks, that seems to have done something, but now it just seems to be outputting random values on each line. The new values I've set are SLCK_PIN to 4, SH_LD_PIN to 1 and DATA_PIN to 7. This is the output I get:
Raw data from shift registers: [16, 66, 74, 8, 33]
Raw data from shift registers: [20, 16, 18, 18, 18]
Raw data from shift registers: [9, 33, 164, 145, 16]
Each of these are on a new line. Could it just be noise or something?

How did you discover the Pi GPIO pin number of the SH/LD pin ? This is not broken out on the Pisound header so the mapping in https://blokas.io/pisound/docs/specs/ cannot be used to work out which it is. It is broken out on the header marked H1 on the schematic but there is no mapping to GPIO pins in that document. You could try a multimeter (ohms range) with one probe on pin 1 (SH) of IC1  (or on any of the SN74HC165NSR chips) and the other on each of the 40 Pi pins until you find it. That you are getting random values may indicate you are currently  using the wrong pin.

On re-reading your original question I see this PCB containing the shift registers is connected only via the Pisound header. That means your only chance is to get at SH on the SN74HC165NSR shift register chain is an extra connection from say pin5 on H1 on that PCB to an unused GPIO pin on the Pi. This because the SH pin is not broken out on the Pisound header. This requires some care to avoid damaging anything.

Ahh good find @6v6gt. I spoke to the PCB designer and he said that I can just use the pin 5 from H2 in the schematic. I've connected it to pin 14 on the PiSound Hat as 13 and 14 weren't being used. The BCM equivalent of 14 is 3, but when I put that as SH_LD_PIN, I still don't get results. Do you know what else could be the issue?

Pins 10 through to 14 on the Pisound header map to gpio pins on the PI which have a specific function on the PI like serial comms, I2C bus etc. You've really got to know what you are doing if you re-use those. You may have to consider adding a separate connection directly between the PCB and the PI. Anyway, if you are talking to the PCB developer then he can best say what your options are.
